# Bazel how to add prefix to dependency?

Tags: bazel

I have two libraries, libA and libB.

both have their own BUILD files.

libA.BUILD looks like this:

```
#libA.BUILD file

cc_library(
    name "libA_foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cc"],
    hdrs = ["foo.h"],
)

cc_library(
    name "libA_bar",
    srcs = ["bar.cc"],
    hdrs = ["bar.h"],
    deps = [":libA_foo"],
)
```

now I want to include some headers of libA in a cc_library in libB

I can do that like so

```
#libB.BUILD file

cc_library(
    name "libB_qux",
    srcs = ["qux.cc"],
    hdrs = ["qux.h"],
    deps = ["@libA//:libA_foo"]
)
```

in qux.cc I would like to include the headers of libA_foo however as `#include "libA/foo.h"` rather than just `#include "foo.h"`

I know that I could add a `include_prefix = "libA"` to `libA_foo`, but then it would mess up the includes of other libraries in libA and I don't want to make changes to libA.

can I somehow declare the prefix when listing the dependency instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Use `include_prefix` to add a prefix to the exported headers of `//libA:libA_foo`.
2. Add `foo.h` in the `srcs` of `//libA:libA_foo` so that they are available without the prefix.
3. Add `foo.h` in the `srcs` of `//libA:libA_bar` as well.

Example:

```
cc_library(
    name "libA_foo",
    srcs = ["foo.cc", "foo.h"],
    hdrs = ["foo.h"],
    include_prefix = "libA",
)

cc_library(
    name "libA_bar",
    srcs = ["bar.cc", "foo.h"],
    hdrs = ["bar.h"],
    deps = [":libA_foo"],
)
```

From the `cc_library` documentation:

> A `.h` file will not be compiled, but will be available for inclusion by sources in this rule. Both `.cc` and `.h` files can directly include headers listed in these `srcs` or in the `hdrs` of any rule listed in the `deps` argument.

Meaning, the `foo.h` in the `srcs` will be accessible by `libA_foo`, and the `foo.h` in the `hdrs` will be accessible by other rules with the include prefix.

Comment: The thing is, I'm http_archive loading libA and can't make changes to the buildfile (other than providing my own build file for it, but if possible I'd like to use the one from this repository)

Comment: That seems like a separate question (consuming a dependency without changing its BUILD file). But anyway, in that situation what I would do is provide a `patches` to the `http_archive` to just patch up the downloaded BUILD file a bit.